# Avoid empty line after full-length footnote

Tags: footnotes

I'm editing a thesis using XeLaTeX. In some pages there are at least two footnotes and sometimes one of them ends with a filled line (I'm not sure this is the best name), so there is an empty line before the next footnote, as shown in the figure [image: empty line between footnotes].

The author of the thesis doesn't like that empty line; is there any way of avoiding those lines?

Edit: a MWE which shows the same problem, but also that the blank line does not always shows up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence.\footnote{ \lipsum[1] } This is another sentence.\footnote{ \lipsum[2] }

This is another paragraph.\footnote{\lipsum*[3]} This is yet another sentence.\footnote{ \lipsum[4] }

\end{document}
```

In the thesis I could get rid of the blank lines by removing a trailing space in the first footnote, as suggested by @David Carlisle. Why isn't there an empty line between footnotes 1 and 2 of the MWE?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I would guess that there's some additional blank somewhere that causes a line break then. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Most likely (you should _always_ show your input document) the line is not empty but contains a space. Don't do `word\footnote{aaa} \footnote{bbb}` with a space (or newline) between the footnotes. do `word\footnote{aaa}\footnote{bbb}`

Comment: There is no space because you are using the `nopar` option of `lipsum`.  This is what you want, normally: no blank space between footnotes.  If you do need/want it, you can modify the footnote-related command(s) in various ways.  Note: using `\footnote{ \lipsum[1] }` gives two spurious spaces in your output; don't do it: write instead `\footnote{\lipsum[1]}`.  Whitespace is important in (La)TeX and rarely ignored.

Comment: If you have a blank line with you real footnotes, please try and make a minimal example *without* `lipsum`.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `\lipsum*[3]` to `\lipsum[3]` including `\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}`, then the footnotes won't have any space between one another.

If you remove `[nopar]` they will gain a little space between them.

Comment: Yes, that's the difference between the first and the second paragraphs. My question is why sometimes a trailing space in a footnote (as in my original document) introduce an empty line between footnotes, and sometimes not (as in the first paragraph of the MWE).

Comment: @MiguelPagano Trailing space? Sorry, I don't understand what you are referring to (my bad :P). The only thing that counts is that asterisk and the `[nopar]` option. I tried spacing randomly the footnotes commands but nothing changes.

Comment: `\lipsum[3]` executes `\par` at the end; the normal behavior of `\footnote` is to add a strut after the footnote text and the trailing `\par` will make the strut start a new paragraph that will appear as an empty line. With `\lipsum*[3]` the trailing `\par` is not inserted.

Comment: I think I have the same problem as @egreg described. Can be the case that the strut also starts a new paragraph if there is a space after the period finishing the footnote? I have to learn what is a strut: any reference?  egreg if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.  Alenanno thanks also for your answer.